# phpmyadmin token mismatch for long time idle

Tags: php, apache, session, phpmyadmin, session-cookies

I installed `phpMyAdmin 4.0.4.1` on my local develop enviroment, I set `auth_type` to `config`. Also I provide authentication requirements by this settings:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'somepassword';
```

But after a while that it is idle, if I click on any link of it , it shows me an error `token mismatch`, Is there any way that I increase its TTL? or make it alive permanently?

[image]

Above picture shows error.

Comment: seems to be a known bug with phpMyAdmin >= 4 : [Token mismatch error on every action](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3893/)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I solve this annoying problem by following instructions below:

1. open `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
2. find `;session.save_path = "/tmp"`, this line may look also like this `;session.save_path = "/var/lib/php5"`
3. remove first semicolon from this line
4. restart apache by executing `sudo service apache2 restart`

FYI: I work under Ubuntu 12.04 with apache2, php5, phpMyAdmin 4.0.5 so for different systems and servers file path may be a little different.

In case of any troubles check if directory from step `2.` is writable for server.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had thought /tmp was the default already (I am also on ubuntu 12.04), so I got session_save_path() to dump the path which is turned out to be /var/lib/php5. Now my question is, why does moving it to /tmp instead of /var/lib/php5 help us/make it work?

Comment: I don't know but the rights are probable cause of this problem. Check the rights for /tmp and /var/lib/php5.

Comment: drwxrwxrwt  35 root   root  4096 Nov  4 14:03 tmp/ and drwx-wx-wt  2 root          root for /var/lib/php5, so it may be the lack of public read. What does t instead of x mean?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea how to solve your problem. If I were you I would try with different permissions sets (http://linux-tipps.blogspot.com/2008/07/directory-rights-in-linux.html).

Comment: Theres no problem, just thought I would link this text for the 't'. "If the text bit is set (chmod o+t), files in the directory can only be deleted by their owner, not the group. But they can still be overwritten, if the files permissions allow that. So it's no real protection." So it appears that in both those directories, only the owner of the files can delete them.

Comment: @Programster Ubuntu has a cleanup script in `/etc/cron.d/php5` which deletes files in `/var/lib/php5`: changing `session.save_path` bypass that cleanup script

Comment: I'll just add to check if the dir exist and is writable. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 9):

in file `libraries/common.inc.php`

line 1076
delete this part

```
 /*
 * There is no point in even attempting to process
 * an ajax request if there is a token mismatch
 */
 if (isset($response) && $response->isAjax() && $token_mismatch) {
    $response->isSuccess(false);
    $response->addJSON(
        'message',
        PMA_Message::error(__('Error: Token mismatch'))
    );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Better to set $token_mismatch to false right after it is tested (about line 487) after the line '$token_mismatch = ($_SESSION[' PMA_token '] != $_REQUEST['token']);' (after the the of the IF statement)

Comment: beware, the token is there for a reason. Ignoring it will open up a range CRSF vulnerabilities: https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Security_Of_phpMyAdmin#CSRF_-_Cross_site_request_forgery

Comment: Where did you find `libraries/common.inc.php`

Answer (score 4):

I had to turn my cookies on in my browser and it worked for me. (Using MAMP on OSX)

Answer (score 3):

For me this seemed to be caused by my root partition being full up, and I guess this error was triggered by php being unable to write to the session directory.

Answer (score 2):

After doing all that was recommended here and in other places with no success, I found out that **my /tmp was full**.

To check it, just run from command line: `df`

It reports file system disk space usage.

Comment: After running `df` command, i got to know that my file system dev/xvda1 was used 100%.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to remove some files to make some space in this directory (\tmp) and the error was gone for now.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing your browser cache then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

To stop this issue, delete the "`tmp`" folder and make a new one called "`tmp`" or just clear the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another browser ex IE if it works then remove suspected chrome extensions .
Forr me pageXray was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ISSUE RESOLVED - 
I just cleared the browsing history and data for last 7 days. It solved the problem for me.
Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I was spend my 2-3 days to solve this problem .. on Stack overflow but i didn't got any working solution for my case.. but
finally..
I solve this annoying problem i was running phpmyadmin from localhost using chrome
but after running from firefox.. PROBLEM IS GONE..

so.. I think that was cookies problem not PMA so.. you should  try with any other browser..