# phpMyadmin giving error of Token Mismatch

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

When I try to click and open any link or database in `phpMyadmin` it results in a Token Mismatch error on my hosting server.
Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: This should probably be placed on ServerFault. Also, reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358867/phpmyadmin-error-mismatch-token

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: this solves same problem for me [phpmyadmin token mismatch for long time idle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076499/phpmyadmin-token-mismatch-for-long-time-idle?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 3):

You need to verify that you have your `session.save_path` setting in your php.ini file set correctly.

After changing to a valid tmp directory, make sure you restart your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

this fixes same error for me
find session.save_path in your php.ini file, this line may look also like this

```
;session.save_path = "/opt/lampp/temp/"
```

remove first semicolon from this line if it there

change it to

```
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```